# Xfce ZOOM Function

Tags: xfce

In Xfce, by default you have the zoom function activated by ALT+(Mouse Wheel).

This is fine for me, but I'd want to add another (and not replace) key combination, for my remote command does not have a mouse wheel.

How can it be done? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As the answer mentions, this is a function of compositing (the functionality disappears if the Compositor is turned off) which means it's probably hard to set it to something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything for this in the advanced XFCE settings editor (xfce4-settings-editor). It might also not work simply because its a function of compositing.

There is a program for automating key presses and mouse clicks/movements called **xdotool** (available from apt). It is supposed to be able to simulate mouse wheel movements using mouse buttons 4 and 5. You can also use it to press the Alt key (on my system its the Super key because I set that to be my XFCE window function key).

Ideally you'd put a command line this in a script file and then run it using another keystroke:

```
xdotool --clearmodifiers keydown Alt click 4 keyup Alt
```

Then make another script that runs the same except click 5 for zooming out.

Comment: Your answer is undoubtably useful (I upvoted it), but I do have only 2 mouse buttons on my Rii fly mouse (It is more a remote than a mouse).

Comment: Well I didn't mean that you'd bind one of your mouse buttons to the zoom function, I meant you'd bind another sequence like Ctrl-Alt- numpad+ and numpad- or something like that.

Comment: Good. Accepted ;)

Comment: Forget the fly mouse, just get a wireless keyboard with a touchpad on it. It might look expensive, but it did wonders for me.  I mean ... what mouse? Where?

Comment: NB: The syntax of the xdotool command has changed. I tried to find something that worked with Alt+Super+=/- and got nowhere. keydown --clearmodifiers Alt isn't going to do what you want. I used Alt+=/- and made them simply xdotool click 4/5. Effective if suboptimal.